# How to set the Legal Page size for PDF created using UIPrintPageRenderer?

Tags: ios, uiprintpagerenderer

I am setting this:

```
static CGFloat LegalPageWidth = 612.0;
static CGFloat LegalPageHeight = 1008.0;
```

as legal page size (i.e 8.5 x 14 inch) for PDF creation in UIPrintPageRenderer as "paperRect" but when I print the PDF its size is always A4 (i.e 612 x 792 = 8.5 x 11 inch).

What is the correct way to get Legal Page size PDF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage creates the new page using the default size while the **UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo** function lets you customize the page size or customize other aspects of the PDF page.

Refer this
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW3